# uwp grab and drag whole window from anywhere like titlebar

Tags: c#, uwp, drag, gesture, uwp-xaml

a UWP app window can be dragged around the screen by holding the title bar, my question is how we can enable same feature on whole window? I mean user can grab the app from literally anywhere within the window of that app. and can drag it around the screen with mouse on a PC or any other touch device or pen input on other devices like tablets and surface hub.?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can override the title bar with:

```
Window.Current.SetTitleBar(UIElement value);
```

If the UIElement you set is a hit target, it will behave like the default title bar and allow you to drag.